# Why people wash their hands before dinner even if they eat with utensils and not hands?

Tags: bacteria, hygiene

Many health professionals advocate washing hand before dinner. But is it necessary if we do not use our hands to directly touch the food we are going to ingest? Can bacteria move from our hands along the utensils or along nearby air towards our mouth?

Comment: It's common that people touch their mouths with the hands during a meal, for example, when they wipe the lips with a tissue. Or there will be a cookie or apple to eat, and they usually hold them with a hand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because its a good habit as your hands might end up touching your mouth or food when you are eating food using spoon or something. Plus eating with dirty hands no matter whether they will touch food or not doesn't just feels right. That's one of the most important reason that people usually wants to feel comfortable while eating and they want their hands to be clean even if they will use a spoon or chopstick. Its also a good idea to just be safe than sorry.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].